# Security warning for some after updating TLS certificate

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, heroku, tls1.2, certificate-authority

My site's TLS certificate was expiring on May 28th, and so I changed it over to a renewed one on May 25th. Since I'm on Heroku I used the command:

```
heroku certs:update server.crt server.key
```

That appeared to work just fine. I (and my team, using various machines) monitored the site over the next day or so to make sure everything was still alright. All seemed to be going well up until a few days ago when we were notified by a few different users that they were getting security warnings. They all appeared to be from Google Chrome with the message:

```
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

I am not sure what I should do here as it seems to be very sporadic and not reproducible on my devices.

If anyone has any tips on why this is happening or how to diagnose the specific user cases I would really appreciate it!

Comment: I think your intermediates chain is incorrect. Test your website with ssllabs.com to confirm.

Comment: the problem is the certificate authority is not trusted in chrome. ¿Who has issued your new certificate? Test with ssllabs to see what it is happenning

Comment: @Tom thanks for the suggestion! I ran my site through it and got A's across the board: http://jodys.pics/331N2G1d2207